# $compile breaks ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am trying to loop over a list of elements generated by an `ng-repeat`, tag them with a directive (in this case `ng-show`), and then re-compile using $compile.  The problem I am running into is that $compile breaks the `ng-repeat` directive and only the comments for the repeat get output.  What am I missing here?

EDIT: This works if I remove the `ng-repeat` directive before running `$compile`. Is this the correct approach or am I still missing something?

My Directive:

```
.directive("imageSlider", [ '$timeout', '$compile', '$rootScope', function($timeout, $compile, $rootScope) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs)
    {
        // Remove image slider attribute from element to prevent infinite loop
        element.removeAttr("image-slider");

        // Set the current slide
        scope.currentSlide = 0;

        // Wait for all other first-round directives to finish
        $rootScope.$on("initialised", function(){
            // Get the slides
            var slides = $("[slide]");

            // Loop over all the slides
            for (var i=0, j=slides.length; i<j; i++) {
                $(slides[i]).attr("ng-show", "currentSlide == " + i);
            };

            // Re-compile the template with the new ng-show attributes
            $compile(element)(scope);
        });
    }
}])
```

Here's what the markup looks like:

```
<div class="image-slider" image-slider>
    <div class="slider-items">
        <a class="slider-item" ng-repeat="slide in page.slides" href="{{slide.link}}" slide>
            <div class="image-container">
                <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" alt="{{slide.title}}">
            </div>
            <div class="excerpt">
                <h1>{{slide.title}}</h1>
                <h2>{{slide.excerpt}}</h2>
                <p class="cta">Learn More &rsaquo;</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Resulting markup block:

```
<div class="image-slider ng-scope">
    <div class="slider-items">
        <!-- ngRepeat: slide in page.slides --><!-- ngRepeat: slide in page.slides --><!-- end ngRepeat: slide in page.slides --><!-- ngRepeat: slide in page.slides --><!-- end ngRepeat: slide in page.slides --><!-- ngRepeat: slide in page.slides --><!-- end ngRepeat: slide in page.slides --><!-- ngRepeat: slide in page.slides --><!-- end ngRepeat: slide in page.slides --><!-- ngRepeat: slide in page.slides --><!-- end ngRepeat: slide in page.slides -->
    </div>
</div>
```

In case you are wondering where the `"initialised"` event is coming from, it's from here:

```
.directive('initialised', ['$rootScope',function($rootScope) {
    return {
        //restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope) {
            var to;
            var listener = $scope.$watch(function(){
                clearTimeout(to);
                to = setTimeout(function() {
                    App.init();
                    listener();
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('initialised');
                }, 150);
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

Comment: Something to note: Your $watch will run with every $digest loop, set a timeout, which will broadcast an 'initialised', which will recompile your contents. So essentially it appears that 150ms after each digest loop you'll be re-compiling your DOM. I'm not sure that is your intention?

Comment: The watch resets itself after every digest, so it basically says 150ms after the last digest fire initialised. This is tested and confirmed to only fire once.